# How can I connect my Galaxy S6 to Ethernet adapter?

Tags: ethernet

I want to connect my S6 with Rj45 to otg cable. I have connected several time with Ethernet cable with not working.

How to enable this option in S6.

Answer (score 0):

OTG cable is based on USB protocol whereas, RJ45 has MAC controller and the communication protocol used is called ethernet. So what you are saying won't work unless you interoperability these two physical mediums and protocols, connect something like this:

[image]

Comment: I have this OTG cable. when i connect this cable to phone that is not working with Galaxy S6. but working with Huawei mate 10pro

Comment: This is specific question for Samsung to answer, i found this [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6-edge/general/enabling-ethernet-usb-otg-t3220476), but consider "all bits are off"